# Show that a function cannot be expressed as a strictly increasing transformation of another function

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, monotone-functions

**This question has been edited thanks to the useful comments below (apologies for my previous mistakes/confusions):**

Consider a function $\Phi: \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are finite sets and $\{0,1\}\subset \mathcal{X}$, $\{0,1\}\subset \mathcal{Y}$.

Assume

(a) $\Phi(0,y)$ and $\Phi(x,0)=0$ $\forall y\in \mathcal{Y}$ and $\forall x \in \mathcal{X}$

(b) $\Phi(1,1)=1$

Consider a function $\tilde{\Phi}: \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose

(c) $\tilde{\Phi}(0,y)$ and $\tilde{\Phi}(x,0)=0$ $\forall y\in \mathcal{Y}$ and $\forall x \in \mathcal{X}$

(d) $\tilde{\Phi}(1,1)=1$

---

**(I)** Does there exist $\tilde{\Phi}$ such that $\Phi$ can be expressed as a strictly increasing transformation of $\tilde{\Phi}$?

**(II)** If the answer to **(I)** is YES, which restrictions (**alternative** to a,b,c,d or **in addition** to a,b,c,d) would guarantee that there does not exists $\tilde{\Phi}$ such that $\Phi$ be expressed as a strictly increasing transformation of $\tilde{\Phi}$?

[For question (II) I'm looking for a sort of "minimal" set of restrictions. For example, I guess that $\tilde{\Phi}(x,y)=\Phi(x,y)$ $\forall (x,y)\in \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$ would make the job, but I would like something weaker]

Comment: I'm not certain enough to leave this as an answer, but, because Phi and Phi bar both have the same domain and codomain, and the same restrictions, couldn't Phi be trivially expressed as the identity function applied to Phi bar?

Comment: There must be more restrictions. The proposition as it is is wrong. A counterexample is $\mathcal I = [0,1],\, \Phi(x)=\sqrt x,\,\tilde\Phi(x)=x^2$, but $\Phi=\sqrt[4]{\tilde\Phi}$ which is a strictly increasing transformation.

Comment: E.D.'s example still applies, i.e. ${\mit \widetilde Φ}={\mit Φ}$ and $f(u)=u$ gives ${\mit \widetilde Φ}=f({\mit Φ})$ with $f$ being strictly increasing.